# Call to a member function setTemplate() during rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select

Tags: overrides

i try to rewrite 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select' this catalog block but i got a error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php on line 197

below is my config.xml file code with file path.

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eventprice_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eventprice_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <eventprice_sql>
                <setup>
                    <module>Eventprice_Meta</module>
                </setup>
            </eventprice_sql>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Block</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
            <adminhtml> 
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                </rewrite>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_options_type_select>Eventprice_Meta_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select</product_view_options_type_select>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

below is my Select.php file code with path.

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
class Eventprice_Meta_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select
extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
       //function code as it is
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite class location name is wrong.

as per as your code class is located at `app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/Select` 
but you define it as `Eventprice_Meta_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`

It should be

`Eventprice_Meta_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`.

Class is should be `same with file path thus autoloader can understand` it path when that file will load

Comment: Hey Amin if i want to change in custom options price then which file or template i need to rewrite?